# Reverse lookup on template page not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a contact and an event model where the event model has a foreign key to contact. The first half of my html obviously works, but for some reason when I display the list of other events that the contact has done, I can't get the list to show up. Is it because I'm calling {{event.whatever}} twice on the same page but in two differrent context?

views.py

```
class EventDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'crm/eventdetail.html'
    model = Event
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=400, null=True, blank=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["lastname"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname


class Event(models.Model):

    event_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = event_types)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    should_follow_up = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('events_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

eventdetail.html

```
<div id="container">
    <h1> Event: {{event.event_type}} </h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Event Contact: {{event.contact}}</li>
        <li>Created By: {{event.created_by}}</li>
        <li>Date: {{event.date}}</li>
        <li>Note: {{event.notes}}</li>
    </ul> 

    <h1>Events for {{event.contact}}</h1>
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Event Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">3</th>
    </tr>

    {% for event in contact.event_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="">{{event.event_type}}</a></td>
        <td> <a href="">{{event.date}}</a></td>
        <td> <a href=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>


<p>This event was inputted on {{event.created}} and last edited on {{event.updated}}</p>


</div>
```

The for loop which is supposed to display all the other events the contact has done is not showing up. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Yeah try changing variable name in `for` loop

Comment: @Moha369 sorry i'm new, can you explain this in steps?

Comment: You said `{% for event ... %}` you created `event` variable while a variable called `event` already exists, so change it to anything else.

Comment: @Moha369 oh ok. would i have to just change it in the for loop or do I have to do something in thew views.py as well?

Comment: Just for loop, change `event` to `event_` or whatever.

Comment: @Moha369 it didn't work :(

Comment: Did you change all variables in the for loop to `event_` or whatever name you've assigned in the for tag ?

Comment: @Moha369 yes I tried that. for instance I put:
  {% for test in contact.event_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="">{{test.event_type}}</a></td>
        <td> <a href="">{{test.date}}</a></td>
        <td> <a href=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

Changes my view

```
class EventDetail(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=kwargs['pk'])
        events = event.contact.eventss.all()
        context = {'event': event, 'events':events}
        return render(request, 'crm/eventdetail.html', context)
```

Added a related_name to my model

```
contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, related_name='eventss', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here is the html file that finally worked

```
 {% for events in event.contact.eventss.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{events.event_type}}</td>
        <td>{{events.date}}</td>
        <td> <a href=""></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```